# Determine the maximum value of $b-a$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with the following property

Tags: number-theory

> If $p$ and $q$ are distinct prime numbers, then there are integers $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $1 = px_0+qy_0$. Determine the maximum value of $b-a$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers with the following property: If $a \leq t \leq b$, and $t$ is an integer, then there are integers $x$ and $y$ with $0 \leq x \leq q-1$ and $0 \leq y \leq p-1$ such that $t = px + qy$.

The first statement is obvious. It follows from Bezout's identity. Also if we want to determine the maximum value of $b-a$ it needs to be for all distinct primes $p,q$, so how do we ensure that?

Comment: By definition of the question the answer is technically $a = -\infty$, $b = \infty$, $b - a = \infty$ to create the maximum value. The question is poorly worded.

Comment: @DaneBouchie So you are saying any integer $t$ can be represented in that form?

Comment: I'm just pointing out the question (I'm guessing you were given) is poorly worded. It asks for the maximum range. I think the meant the minimum value of $b-a$, for all $t$ such that ... etc.

Comment: @DaneBouchie It says determine the maximum possible value of $b-a$ with the following property... so the answer isn't $\infty$.

Comment: Well as long as $t$ is some positive integer, we simply pick the largest values such that $a <= t <= b$. Therefore we choose $a = 0$ and $b = \infty$ to get $b-a = \infty$. $\infty$ is the maximum possible value of $b-a$. (Corrected that $a$ needs to be a positive integer)

Comment: I'm just being technical. This isn't the answer you are looking for, but it technically is the answer.

Comment: @DaneBouchie Any $t$ in that range has to work and you haven't proven that.

Comment: That's what's not specified in the question. It's missing $\forall t$, $a <= t <= b$

Comment: @DaneBouchie It is clearly specified: "If $a \leq t \leq b$ and $t$ is an integer..."

Comment: $t$ is a single integer, it does not specify for all $t$ in that range. It only has to apply for a single integer $t$ in that range.

Comment: @DaneBouchie No, it is for all $t$ in that range.

Comment: That's how the question should be. $t$ is poorly defined. I'm not going to argue this anymore because everyone can infer that's what the question actually meant. However, the question should still be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If $t<p$ and $t<q$, then you can't have $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ with $t=px+qy$.
So $a\geq\min(p,q)$.
And the highest possible value for $t$ is $p(q-1)+q(p-1)$,
so $b\leq2pq-p-q$.
There are probably tighter bounds than that though.
If $p=3$ and $q=5$, the possible numbers are: 
$$0,3,6,9,12;5,8,11,14,17;10,13,16,19,22\\
=0,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16,17,19,22$$
so the largest value of $b-a$ comes for $a=8$ and $b=14$.

Comment: Try $2\&3$, $2\&5$, $2\&7$, $3\&5$, $3\&7$,$5\&7$ until you find a pattern for $a$ or $b$ or $b-a$

Comment: I am not seeing a pattern. Can you tell me how to solve this? It looks symmetric.

Comment: I get $0,2,3,4,5,7$ for $2,3$ and $0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,13$ for $2,5$.

Comment: Draw up a table with five columns p,q,a,b,b-a.  The first row, from your results, is 2,3,2,5,3.  When you have a few rows, try to find a connection between p,q, and the other columns.